# Loading image from iphone in Unity3d

Tags: c#, .net, ios, unity-game-engine

I send image path to unity using iOS Unity plugin. And in Unity I try to get this image using received path (I have no other idea how to send image from iphone to unity). The problem: I still can't get the image. 
**WWW Error: The requested URL was not found on this server.**

```
//Tried both "file:///..." and "file://..."
string path = "file://var/mobile/Applications/173DE26D-4C0E-4DF7-9DC6-9CBB7D4FC954/Documents/Images/image.png" 

Texture texture;

IEnumerator WaitForRequest(WWW www) {
    yield return www;

    if (www.error == null) {
        texture = www.texture;
    }    
}

void Start() {
    WWW www = new WWW(path);
    StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www));
}
```

Comment: Do you just want to access a local file in order to load a texture or will it be located out there in the web later on?

Comment: I just want to access local file in order to load a texture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the file is there using

```
System.IO.File.Exists("/var/mobile/Applications/173DE26D-4C0E-4DF7-9DC6-9CBB7D4FC954/Documents/Images/image.png")
```

because your code looks correct.

Also, instead of hardcoding the path you should use Application.persistentDataPath.

```
string path = "file://" + System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "Images/image.png");
```

BTW, I think an absolute file url should always start with `file:///`.

Comment: I hardcoded path for simplicity of code example - in project it's dynamic. And the problem was in wrong path - my fault)