# Get image from iphone gallery for unity3D game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm beginner in programming, I need create method for change avatar in IOS game, I created game in unyti3D, similar function is in it [link](https://github.com/thedoritos/unimgpicker) project but now isn't work,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading image from iphone in Unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158837/loading-image-from-iphone-in-unity3d)

Comment: sorry but is Not duplicated, I need change avatar selected her from gallery and add to new icon

Comment: sorry it's bad question but I dont know...i'm disappointed

Comment: You will easily find assets on the [Unity Asset Store](http://assetstore.unity3d.com) to do what you want. (Less than 10 dollars)

Comment: If you have difficulties with an asset you find, the best idea is to ask the developper(s) ;) (meaning, you should open an issue on the Git of the asset you've found)